# Wiring diagram software

Tags: wiring, official-foundation

I am looking to document a hardware project my company is putting together.  It consists of a Raspberry Pi prototype board and some basic circuitry.

The tutorials on raspberrypi.org have very nice wiring diagrams; for example, the image below.  I would like to generate similar-looking diagrams for my documentation.  Does anybody know what software they use to generate these images and if I can use it for my own projects?

[image: raspberrypi.org wiring diagram]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Assuming here you want to create similar images to what Raspberrypi.org provides (your question asks how the images are made, but you do not provide a reason why you want to know this): You can create similar diagrams using the Fritzing open source circuit design software, downloadable at http://fritzing.org/home/.

Output looks like this:
[image]

You can then turn these circuits into PCB designs, and even order your PCB printed right from Fritzing itself. Outputs generated are compatible with what most PCB service need as inputs.

Comment: I recommend donating, but if you can't usually the releases are in https://github.com/fritzing/fritzing-app/releases

Answer (score 19):

I believe they have their own in-house designer who created the images you're referring to, as discussed [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/resources-restyled/):

> Our new in-house designer Sam has produced the templates along with a
>   brilliant set of icons, components, characters, illustrations and
>   bespoke GPIO and wiring diagrams.

That being the case, the likely candidates are Illustrator and Photoshop. There is a repository of reusable image resources on the [Raspberry Pi Learning GitHub page](https://github.com/raspberrypilearning/components/tree/master/components).

Comment: Thanks for the GitHub link; it's a great starting point!  The images there are very useful; looks like it would still be a manual process to get the final result.

Answer (score 8):

## DIY with GIMP

Based on the [education resources](https://github.com/raspberrypilearning) of the Raspberry Pi Foundation and the [SVGs of Fritzing](https://github.com/fritzing/fritzing-parts/tree/master/svg/core/breadboard), you can create your own diagrams with [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/):

[image: breadboard_and_raspi]

Example images:

- [Raspberry Pi 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfJO6.png)
- [Raspberry Pi 3 B+](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJNfX.png)
- [breadboard](https://github.com/fritzing/fritzing-parts/blob/12f12d6c74c91ab77ac31e332fc87418f2a5b848/svg/core/breadboard/breadboard2.svg)
- [red LED](https://github.com/fritzing/fritzing-parts/blob/12f12d6c74c91ab77ac31e332fc87418f2a5b848/svg/core/breadboard/LED-3mm-red-leg.svg)
- [220 Ω resistor](https://github.com/fritzing/fritzing-parts/blob/12f12d6c74c91ab77ac31e332fc87418f2a5b848/svg/core/breadboard/resistor_220.svg)
- [push button](https://github.com/fritzing/fritzing-parts/blob/12f12d6c74c91ab77ac31e332fc87418f2a5b848/svg/core/breadboard/basic_pbutton.svg)

I used [paths](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-using-paths.html) in GIMP to draw the jumper wires. Watch this [tutorial](https://youtube.com/watch?v=e3nvFRrM0og) to see how that's done.

---

### Licensing¹

The education resources of the Raspberry Pi Foundation are licensed under [Creative Commons Attribution Share-Alike 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) meaning you are free to create new diagrams based on theirs. You have to attribute the Raspberry Pi Foundation by, for example, linking back to their web site.

If you publish your work, you have to license your work under the same license.

The Fritzing images are licensed under [Creative Commons Attribution Share-Alike 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), an earlier version of the same license.

¹ I'm not a lawyer.